# iPhone/iPod - prevent font-size-changing

Tags: iphone, css, orientation, ipod

I was wondering whether it is possible to prevent following behaviour:
I've got a *.css file in which I define the font-size for my mobile-web-app.

html,body {
    font-size:16px !important;
}

I didn't use any other font-size attributes in my files.
Now, when I turn into the landscape mode, the font-size changes.
How can I prevent or manipulate this behaviour. Do I have to use `@media screen and (max-width: x px) { }` or is there any other way?

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may need to use extra selectors but the following should do the trick.

```
html,body { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
```

So that this rule doesn't prevent text resizing in WebKit desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari and soon Opera), wrap it in a CSS media query targeting the desired devices like so:

```
/* iPhone, portrait & landscape. */
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    html,body { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
}
/* iPad, portrait & landscape. */
@media all and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    html,body { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
}
```

Comment: A warning: This css rule affects all webkit browsers, including desktop ones, and prevents desktop users from changing their font-size using browser zoom. As such, I don't recommend you use it without a media query to target just mobiles.

Comment: @Steve any alternatives to achieve iOS-only results?

Comment: @Dan I've added Steve's input to my answer.