# Strange Formatting Issue with basic HTML

Tags: android, html, html-table

Okay, this is driving me nuts. I've been troubleshooting a formatting issue and have been stripping and stripping the code down and no explanation for what I see.

Look at the following page:

http://test.solivitahoa.com/testbig.php

VERY simple HTML. No CSS, no JS, just a table with 2 columns. If you view it on your desktop, it's fine and looks as expected. HOWEVER, if you view it in Chrome on Android (I'm running Android 8 on OnePlus 5), the first cell has text that is much smaller than the right cell even though there is no sizes specified in the code.

The formatting is as expected until the last "1234567890" is set on the first line and then it increases the font size.

What causes this? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

That is od. One way to fix it is to set a fixed text size on the whole document. For example, this css fixes the issue:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

You can consider this your font reset css.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that this code is part of a much larger site with lots of various formatting and such. I'm wondering if it's a bug in Android Chrome.

Comment: Why don't you just explicitly set the font-size just for that class/table/etc.? It seems like mobile devices can do some adjusting based on the size of the cell. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917088/how-to-prevent-mobile-devices-to-scale-font-size

Some suggestions: Ensure viewport scaling is set to 1: 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Some people suggesting these css properties:
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
-moz-text-size-adjust: none;
-ms-text-size-adjust: none;