# CSS font not what it should be (mobile)

Tags: html, css, fonts

Edit: This problem appears on mobile devices or when using mobile device emulators in dev tools

This is very strange problem to me. There's no inline CSS or anything, just one line of CSS that says "font-size: 10px;" yet in chrome the font size is not that.

[image]

It says right there the font is 10px in the CSS, then 23.6 displayed. Why? This makes no sense.

Code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-ac-color);
  webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#overall {
  color: #313131;
  height: auto;
}

#about {
  z-index: 9;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#about .inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  min-width: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#about-text {
  background-color: var(--main-ac-color);
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  font-family: 'Cutive Mono', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="overall">
    <div id="about">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>&mdash; About &mdash;</h1>
        <div class="boom">
          <div id="about-text">
            <p>
              Test Text
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

the class "boom" is for scrollreveal and has no properties

Here's a JSFiddle. The best I can replicate the problem is to open this JSFiddle, open developer tools on chrome, and change it to emulate a mobile device (like iPhone 6), then the text inside in the blue "Hello World" box will be larger than 10px, whereas the other text, such as the list of courses, will be exactly 10px. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jp3isme/os1385Lb/1/

Comment: Please show us your code, not just a image. Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: share your code!

Comment: @PatrickMlr I updated the post, but there's really no code to show. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: That's all CSS code of your site? Which HTML `tag` are you using which have `23.6715px`?

Comment: Hold on, there's a little more, but none of it changes font. I'll add it @PatrickMlr

Comment: @PatrickMlr I've added the rest

Comment: You want to know why "-- About --" is this huge?

Comment: No, the test text. But I've just realized why. I had the developer tools environment on "iPhone 6 Plus". Why is the text scaled this way? Edit: That must not be entirely why. In other places on the site the text stays 10px, yet this problem goes away when i leave the "iPnone 6 Plus" emulator.

Comment: In this example, I can't see the problem. That problem is hard to solve. Maybe you could provide a working snippet which works like your site. Try to use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something like this.

Comment: Does the file mobile.css (in the screenshot) contain other font sizes?

Comment: @MrLister I went as far as making a duplicate of the project and removing all *other references to font-size everywhere in the CSS, so no. I'll try making a jsFiddle

Comment: min-width:none is not a valid value, should be 0, the same for min-height. Maybe those errors are breaking your sheet

Comment: @tourdefran No, errors like that are quietly ignored. There are no browsers that have real problems with them.

Comment: @tourdefran Thanks, I removed it. Unfortunately didn't fix it

Comment: JSFiddle added @PatrickMlr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see the problem. It's because the mobile Browser will automatically change the size of the font.

*I don't know why the problem only appears if you use your "example code" but not if you just add some text with the dev tool.*

You could prevent that if you add this:

```
body, html {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -o-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

See MDN here: [MDN: text-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust)

> Because many web pages have not been developed with mobile in mind, smartphone browsers differ from desktop browsers in the way they display web pages. Instead of laying out the web page at the width of the device screen, they lay it out using a viewport that is much wider than the device screen, usually 800 or 1000 pixels wide. To map the wide layout back to the original device size, the browser either shows only part of the whole render, or the viewport is scaled down to fit.

---

Other similar questions:

1. [How to prevent mobile devices to scale font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917088/how-to-prevent-mobile-devices-to-scale-font-size)
2. [iPhone/iPod - prevent font-size-changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094324/iphone-ipod-prevent-font-size-changing)

Other helpful site:

1. [Preventing Mobile Safari from upscaling font sizes](http://www.kaspertidemann.com/preventing-mobile-safari-from-upscaling-font-sizes/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it only scaled the font in that one section? Other places on the site the font stayed size 10. Is that font specific?

Comment: There you're using the `<p>` tag, in other sections a `table`.