# How to ignore the phone's font size setting with CSS?

Tags: android, css, ios, responsive, font-size

I have a web app that is mostly used in mobile devices. It look goods on mobile phone, but after increase the font-size in system settings, it look quite hideous. Is there any CSS tricks or hack or cheats to get it look the same no matter what the font-size configuration is? Thank you so much!

| Normal Look | After Setting | Horrified look |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Looks good] | [image: font setting] | [image: Horified] |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS to avoid this from happening:

```
html,body {
  text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late accepting!

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding `text-size-adjust: none;` css to your html body tag, it'll prevent text size increasing. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094355/4896949).

```
html,body {
  text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wish I could accept both you and the above answer :sweat_smile